# What is wrong with my Rx-js groupJoin

Tags: javascript, rxjs

The following code:

```
const Rx = require('rx');

const gameRowObservable = Rx.Observable.fromArray([{
    game_id: 1,
    game_name: "game one",
}, {
    game_id: 2,
    game_name: "game two",
}]);
const playerRowObservable = Rx.Observable.fromArray([{
    game_id: 1,
    player_id: 1,
    player_name: "player one",
}, {
    game_id: 1,
    player_id: 2,
    player_name: "player two",
}, {
    game_id: 2,
    player_id: 3,
    player_name: "player three",
}, {
    game_id: 2,
    player_id: 4,
    player_name: "player four",
}]);

const rowObservable = gameRowObservable.
groupJoin(
    playerRowObservable,
    gameRow => Rx.Observable.return(gameRow.game_id),
    playerRow => Rx.Observable.return(playerRow.game_id),
    (gameRow, playerGroup) => playerGroup.toArray().map(playerGroup => Object.assign(gameRow, {
        player_list: playerGroup
    }))
).mergeAll();

rowObservable.subscribe(row => console.log(row));
```

produces the following result:

```
{ game_id: 1, game_name: 'game one', player_list: [] }
{ game_id: 2, game_name: 'game two', player_list: [] }
```

I would like to get this result:

```
[{
    game_id: 1,
    game_name: "game one",
    player_list: [{
        game_id: 1,
        player_id: 1,
        player_name: "player one",
    }, {
        game_id: 1,
        player_id: 2,
        player_name: "player two",
    }]
}, {
    game_id: 2,
    game_name: "game two",
    player_list: [{
        game_id: 2,
        player_id: 3,
        player_name: "player three",
    }, {
        game_id: 2,
        player_id: 4,
        player_name: "player four",
    }]
}]
```

So I basically want the players per game as an array property. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `merge`& `scan` could be a better choice. But why the downvote? That also could help (`GroupJoin - Joins two streams matching by one of their attributes`) : http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc39

Comment: Thanks for the link! This seems like an O(n2) solution where the entire players list is scanned for every game. So for 100 games with a list of 200 players, the players list would be scanned 200 * 100 = 200000 times! Such a solution would be unneccasary inefficient,

Comment: I would encourage you then to specify your mandatory requirements in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I can't provide a working solution using, but I hope I can help you on the right track.

As you can see in the documentation of [groupJoin](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/groupjoin.md), the second and third parameters are meant to determine **durations** rather than **attribute values** by which to group.

You're effectively grouping by overlap, i.e. starting with the emitting of gameRowA, any playerRows emitted before the next gameRow is emitted are grouped with gameRowA. As you don't want any fancy grouping, your duration selectors are just your source observables. See [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/foxozabeya/edit?js,console)

```
const rowObservable = gameRowObservable.
groupJoin(
    playerRowObservable,
    gameRow => gameRowObservable,
    playerRow => playerRowObservable,
    (gameRow, playerGroup) => playerGroup.toArray().map(playerGroup => Object.assign(gameRow, {
        player_list: playerGroup
    }))
).mergeAll();

rowObservable.subscribe(row => console.log(row));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am aware that the durations used in the exampe are time values, but AFAIK these do not neccesary have to be time values. I assume this operator behaves something like the `groupJoin` operator in LINQ or IxJS. I would be surprised if they don't.

Comment: Well, I am very surprised after reading this http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/join.html definition of the join operator that suggests there is always a time component in a join function. So I guess you were right about the durations and I was stupid to think it would mean anything other than a time duration!

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't been able to set up the code according to the example given previously (http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc39), here is a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/t2bjy03p/2/):

```
var gameRowObservable
    = Rx.Observable.fromArray([
                                {game_id : 1, game_name : "game one" },
                                {game_id : 2, game_name : "game two" }
                              ]);
var playerRowObservable
    = Rx.Observable.fromArray([
                                {game_id : 1, player_id : 1, player_name : "player one"},
                                { game_id : 1, player_id : 2, player_name : "player two"},
                                {game_id : 2, player_id : 3, player_name : "player three"},
                                {game_id : 2, player_id : 4, player_name : "player four"}
                              ]);

var rowObservable = gameRowObservable.
    groupJoin(
    playerRowObservable,
    function () {return Rx.Observable.merge(gameRowObservable, playerRowObservable).last()},
    function () {return Rx.Observable.never()},
    function ( gameRow, playerRowObservable ) {
      return playerRowObservable
          .filter(function ( playerRow ) {
                    return playerRow.game_id === gameRow.game_id
                  })
          .toArray()
          .map(function(player_list){return Object.assign(gameRow, {
        player_list: player_list})})
    })
    .mergeAll();

rowObservable.subscribe(function ( row ) {console.log(row)});
```

In the console, you should see exactly your expected output.

Some explanations:

- `groupJoin` groups based on duration selectors. The standard documentation is pretty dense for this complex operator, I think it is more clear here : http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/join.html
- it is kind of difficult to explain clearly with words, so here is a test that clarifies things : https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/86405588/ (look only the first one `GroupJoinOp_Normal_I`)
- in short you define time windows, and whichever items coinciding in these windows are paired together according to a selector function you define. That function takes two parameters : first will receive items from the first observable, second will be an observable whose elements will be the items from the second observable in the same window (really have a look at the test, it is more clear).
- so here, you want to pair any game_id which any subsequent player. So basically you don't want to ever close your grouping window till both of the source observables have completed. Hence this particular choice of duration selectors
- then it is your code to group things into an object containing `player_list`.
- the observable returned by `groupJoin` will then emit an observable with only one element which completes soon after emitting that element.
- `mergeAll` to flatten the resulting observable of observables

There might be a slightly shorter way. I don't have so much time to investigate, but if you do, please post the results here. I haven't seen many questions about this operator, so any information is always welcome.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This will produce the output I desire, but in a quite inefficient way. For every game the entire players list wel be iterated and that would result in  O(n2) ish behaviour. I am looking for a RxJS solution that will loop each list once(ish).This is quite easy to achieve with a 'normal' js approach using `reduce` but I am curious why the RxJS solution does not work!

Comment: You could then use `merge` & `scan` (the equivalent of `reduce`) as I was telling you in my first comment. That is also much simpler. In any case, your posted question (which was about `groupJoin`) is answered. For an updated answer, you should update your question.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being I use a non-rx solution. I would be if the thing I want is not possible with RxJS, but it kind of seems that duration actually refers to a time duration.

FYI the solution I use now goes a little something like this:

```
const gameRows = [{
    game_id: 1,
    game_name: "game one",
}, {
    game_id: 2,
    game_name: "game two",
}];
const playerRows = [{
    game_id: 1,
    player_id: 1,
    player_name: "player one",
}, {
    game_id: 1,
    player_id: 2,
    player_name: "player two",
}, {
    game_id: 2,
    player_id: 3,
    player_name: "player three",
}, {
    game_id: 2,
    player_id: 4,
    player_name: "player four",
}];

gameRows.sort((a, b) => a.game_id - b.game_id);
playerRows.sort((a, b) => a.game_id - b.game_id);

/*
in the thing I am building, I get the two lists from a database and sort them
in the database!
*/

const playerRowCount = playerRows.length;

var playerRowIndex = 0;
const rows = gameRows.map(gameRow => {
    const player_list = [];
    while (playerRowIndex < playerRowCount && playerRows[playerRowIndex].game_id === gameRow.game_id) {
        player_list.push(playerRows[playerRowIndex]);
        playerRowIndex++;
    }
    return Object.assign({
        player_list
    }, gameRow);
});

rows.forEach(row => console.log(row));
```

I am still very curious about an efficient RxJS solution, if it exists.

Comment: I stick to a not rx solution, I was hoping RxJS was something like LINQ (or async IxJS) but it seems that it is not! Too bad...

Comment: `For every game the entire players list wel be iterated and that would result in O(n2) ish behaviour.`. Is that not the case here too?

Comment: Nope, both list are iterated, and when the game_id from both items are not the same the players list iteration is paused. When game_id is the same the iteration of the players list is continued. Noth lists are iterated once.

Comment: I see, this holds as you sorted both list beforehand according  to the same keys. Fair enough, but then you have to add the complexity of sorting both list (is that `nlog(n)` for most of the algorithms?).    Other thing to take into account with performance is that the `O` estimation is not all the story. If you use `merge`&`scan` implementation based on javascript object hashmap, that could be fast too (almostO(1)), because the hashmap lookup is done internally. But then you can use the same technique without Rxjs too. If these are two arrays that you want to join, no need tor asynchronicity.

Comment: True, that could be an even faster solution! Also I agree on that O is not everything. I choose this solution because I can sort in the database and I might stream the rows from the database in the future. Actually I was hoping RxJS groupJoin could maybe help me with that.

Comment: got you. So is there a need to specify now the approach with `merge` & `scan` (actually an approach with `merge` and `groupBy` might work too but that will create an observable for each `game_id` which apparently you don't need, so not the most performant) or you'll get there when you have the need?